# WIX MSI - PROPERTY override precedence

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Any help will be much appreciated.

I'm writing this WIX installer to get an MSI to install a web app on our servers.

Within my app, I have this PROPERTY - "WEBDIR". I use this property later in my code as a Directory Id.

I set this property in 3 ways.

1. (Method 'A') As a property passed when you call msiexec in quiet mode. [Setting it here as C:\Path1] Like so:

   ```
   msiexec /quiet /i My.msi WEBDIR="C:\Path1" /l*v InstallationLog.log
   ```
2. (Method 'B') From an IniFileSearch. I have an ini file in C:\Windows called MySetup.ini where the key WebsitesDir resolves the value C:\Path2. [Setting it here as C:\Path2]:

   ```
   <Property Id="WEBDIR">
       <IniFileSearch Id="WebsitesDirIni" Name="MySetup.ini" Section="InstallLocations" Key="WebsitesDir" Type="raw"/>
   </Property>
   ```
3. (Method 'C') Using a default directory structure. [Setting it here as C:\Path3] As follows:

   ```
   <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
       <Directory Id="WEBDIR" Name="Path3">
       </Directory>
   </Directory>
   ```

The way it currently works is as follows:
 - When Methods 'A', 'B' and 'C' all set the property value, B takes precedence.
 - When only Methods 'A' and 'C' set the property value, 'C' takes precedence.

What I want is to be able to set the order of precedence to 'A'. If !'A' then 'B' else 'C'.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. If you want to control the order the best approach would be an [immediate custom action](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx). Since it needs to set an installer property, your custom action must receive the installation handle (a win32 DLL is recommended).

Under normal circumstances the installer will use this order:

1. A command line value initializes the property
2. A directory row sets the initial folder path, overriding the command line value. This path can be later modified by costing actions ([CostFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
3. A search overrides the initial folder path, but may be overridden by costing actions.